# 12 months rolling

Tags: postgresql

I have the query below which returns 12 months rolling data.  So if I run it today it brings data back from 23rd August 2015 to 23rd August 2016.  Now ideally I would like it to start from the 1st August 2015 and if I was to run it again next month it would start from 1stSeptember 2015.  Is this possible to do?  Thanks

```
select

Date
Street
Town
Incidents
IncidentType A
IncidentType B
IncidentType C

FROM
(

select

COUNT(I.INC_NUM) as Incidents,

COUNT(case when i.INC_TYPE = ''A'' THEN 1
  end)
"IncidentType A"
COUNT(case when i.INC_TYPE = ''B'' THEN 1
  end)
"IncidentType B"
COUNT(case when i.INC_TYPE = ''C'' THEN 1
  end)
"IncidentType C"

FROM Table i


GROUP BY i.INC_NUM

) i

where Date >= (now()-('12 months'::interval))
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code suggests that you are using Postgres.  If the code works and you just need to adjust the `where` clause, use `date_trunc()`:

```
where Date >= date_trunc('month', now() - ('12 months'::interval))
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon this is great, much appreciated